# Enqueue style for specific site type

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I want to import a style only on specific site types (articles (single.php), categories (category.php) and 404 page (404.php)). I tried to use is_page() but I don't know if it works for different site types. Thank you for your help.

**Update**
this is what I tried

```
wp_register_style('style-narrow', '/wp-content/themes/my theme/css/style-article-narrow.css');
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('style-narrow', 'general', '1.0', 'screen');
    }
```

and

```
wp_register_style('style-narrow', '/wp-content/themes/my theme/css/style-article-narrow.css');
        if ( is_page_template( 'category.php' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_style('style-narrow', 'general', '1.0', 'screen');
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/287547/edit) and paste in the relevant code, to show us what you've tried so far. This will make it easier for us to provide useful answers.

Comment: you can call `wp_enqueue_style` in the template file.

Comment: It is working, but only before wp_head() is called, so I have to create a new header

Answer (score 1):

`is_tax()` and `is_404()` perhaps?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

---

**UPDATE:**

I'm sorry my original answer was vague, to elaborate better:

You can add conditional tags in a `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, choosing to register and enqueue when criteria is met, like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mythemes_scripts' );
function mythemes_scripts() {

    if (is_category()) {
        wp_register_style(
            'categoryStyles',  
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-category.css', 
            array(), // maybe the primary style.css handle here 
            filemtime( get_template_directory() . '/style-category.css' )
        );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'categoryStyles');
    }

    if (is_404()) {
        wp_register_style(
            'fourohfourStyles',  
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-404.css', 
            array(), // maybe the primary style.css handle here 
            filemtime( get_template_directory() . '/style-404.css' )
        );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fourohfourStyles');
    }

}
```

The codex link above has many more conditional tags for situations like `is_archive()`.

I've put `"// maybe the primary style.css handle here"` as doing so makes the main style sheet load before your conditional style sheets - so any CSS redefinitions are overwriting properly.

The `filemtime()` for version numbering (instead of '1.0') will help with cache-breaking, which is valuable while trying to troubleshoot with multiple CSS includes that are presumably redefining.

And if this code is for a plugin instead of a theme you can swap `get_template_directory_uri()`/`get_template_directory_uri()` out for `plugins_url()`/`plugin_dir_path()` respectively.

Comment: This is probably correct, but as it stands it reads more like a comment. Please expand it (perhaps with a code sample) to be more helpful. See [How do I write a good answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not working for me (maybe I'm doing something wrong..) code: if ( is_404() ) {
   wp_enqueue_style('style-narrow', 'general', '1.0', 'screen');
  }

Comment: sorry, I've updated my post. With the above I was able to get individual .css files to load for Category pages, 404 pages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mmm pointed out, I could also use wp_enqueue_style in my template file, so I created another header (header_single.php) with

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style('style-narrow', 'general', '1.0', 'screen'); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Note that the style has to be enqueued before `wp_head()` is called.